# How high should be the handle of a balance bike for a 35 inches tall kid?

Tags: children

How should I decide about handle adjustment?

Handle is adjustable upto 20 inches.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this over the internet. You should work with a local bike shop -- and most importantly -- your child, to determine what the appropriate height is.

Comment: If they are flat bars then about seat height is what you see on mtn bikes

Comment: The only person who knows the right height is the kid on the bike.  Ask him/her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should adjust a balance/strider bike so that:

- When sitting on the seat their feet are flat on the ground with a
  slight bend at the knees.
- The handlebars are at about mid-torso height.

I usually tell people to worry about saddle height first, then handlebar adjustments.

Comment: I wonder why hasn't any experienced member of this community up voted this! I treat up votes as a way of knowing whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: I use my recumbent bike as kind of balance bike for short distances and the handlebars are just higher than mid torso. They are a bit high for comfort but can be used this style. I would like to buy full size modern strider bike but have not found one yet. (I have used an old model in a museum and liked the fun of it.)